# how to redirect to global error page if the user entered wrong page name or wring parameter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config

I want to redirect to errorpage.aspx if the user entered wrong page name or wrong parameters in the url.

Eg: Actual URL is **http://live.rex.com/Page1.aspx**
 But, user entered the url like **http://live.rex.com/Pa**

So,how can i handle this type of exceptions.

I tried with httpmodules remove key in Web.Config file and also tried with defaulturl. But, no luck.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Have you tried this microsoft link? http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Comment: Yes  WraithNath, i tried with the link what you have sent. Its wotrking for all the scenarios except "http://live.rex.com/pa" which means invalid parameters in the URL. In this condition, its showing error. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it in `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
                  defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Error.aspx" />    
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Dumpty. I want to know is it possible to do like for 404 error "HTTP404.aspx", for general exceptions "error.aspx" and for session invalid "SessionInvalid.aspx". I tried with  WraithNath url and its not working with one condition as i described in comment. Please help me.

Comment: You can use [PostAcquireRequestState Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate.aspx) for `session` expire?

Comment: K, can i declare redirect errorpage urls globally in one place to handle all this type of errors?

Comment: By default, when an error occurs it will re-diret to the page you define in the web.config

Comment: Yes Dumty, its going for all the conditions except "http://live.rex.com/pa" scenario. I want to redirect to error page in this invalid params in the url conditions. Hope i am clear on this.

Comment: If this is identifying as a valid page by default, you might need to use [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.ASPX) to catch these king of url and redirect to a custom page!!